# Jira AQL - REST API - PHP Request - Params ignored

Tags: php, jira-rest-api

Hope you're all fine,

I'm trying to perform some automations over my Jira and right now I'm using PHP to perform an API REST call to return ASSETS

The documentation I use is this: [AQL API REST](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/assets/rest/api-group-aql)

The PHP code sample given in the documentation uses the [Unirest library](http://unirest.io/php.html)

Anyway, this is the first time I try to perform and API call using PHP

I have done this before in Python 3 and have worked (using the [Requests library](https://pypi.org/project/requests/))

The PHP project that I'm working with it uses the [CURL setpot function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) to perform API calls

So, this is the situation, and current code:

Situation: I have an ASSET called Books, and there are over 25 of it, so, I have to use the PAGE param (because AQL API calls only retrieve 25 ASSETS, starting in PAGE 1) and iterate until I get all of the Books

Current code: The logical is right, and the PAGE param increases with each iteration and stops when reach the total number of Books, but, the API call ignores the param, so, the PAGE 1 is retrieved multiple times...

The code (I'm not putting the while cycle that I use to not make it longer, just the API call)

```
$assets_page = 1;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array
(
   CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.atlassian.com/jsm/assets/workspace/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx/v1/aql/objects?qlQuery=objectSchemaId=1%20AND%20objectTypeId=1',
   CURLOPT_USERPWD => 'username:token',
   CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
   CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\"page\":".$assets_page."}",
   CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type: application/json'),
   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true             
 )
);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$decoderesult = json_decode($result);
print_r($decoderesult);
```

If anyone has any idea of how to make, it would be quite apreciatte it

Thanks in advance
Best regards,

Comment: A GET request with CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, how is that supposed to make sense in the first place? And I don't see it saying anywhere, that you should send JSON to begin with? It says "QUERY PARAMETERS" there, and since the method is GET, I would assume you simply have to put them into the query string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it

If anyone interested, the thing was to

- delete the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS
- add the parameters in the URL after a **&** and using **=** instead of **:** like

```
$assets_page = 1;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array
(
   CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.atlassian.com/jsm/assets/workspace/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx/v1/aql/objects?qlQuery=objectSchemaId=1%20AND%20objectTypeId=1&page='.strval($assets_page),
   CURLOPT_USERPWD => 'username:token',
   CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
   CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type: application/json'),
   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true             
 )
);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$decoderesult = json_decode($result);
print_r($decoderesult);
```